# Stack overflow when starting spark streaming from a checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, stack-overflow, spark-streaming, checkpointing

When restarting spark streaming from a checkpoint I got this exception.
Because it's not related to any code I had produce I have no idea what can cause this problem.

Any idea?

```
Exception in thread "streaming-start" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InternalMapWithStateDStream.compute(MapWithStateDStream.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
...
...
a lot a line that don't satisfy stack overflow . com
...
...
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InternalMapWithStateDStream.compute(MapWithStateDStream.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InternalMapWithStateDStream.compute(MapWithStateDStream.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InternalMapWithStateDStream.compute(MapWithStateDStream.scala:134)
```

Edit : I have upgraded from the 1.6.0 to spark 2.0.2. And I still have this error

Comment: Looks like a recursion, a non-terminating one. Can you please share the code as well?

Comment: Which code ? the application it self have 20K lines. And spark should have the same number of lines.

Comment: @crak , we are experiencing the same error (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18805) with Spark 1.6.3. Did you manage to overcome this issue?

Comment: As turn around remove the checkpoint files